# How can I use platform (or shell) specific environment variable values?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am defining custom tasks using the `tasks.json` file in MS Visual Studio Code. It is great that there are a load of predefined variables available such as `${relativeFile}` or `${fileBasename}` available as defined in the [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference), but the *values* of these are (on my Windows platform) always Windows-specific, such as:

`${relativeFile}` resolves to (say) `c:\Users\SHarrop\Desktop\dev\myFile.txt`

This is not helpful when I have set my default shell to be **bash** (expecting forward slashes). I feel there must be a better answer than "**If you use pre-populated variables in your tasks on a Windows platform, then you need to use the Windows shell**". Similarly I might be passing such variables as arguments into scripts that expect Unix-style paths.

Is there any way of getting Unix-flavored values on a Windows platform?

Thanks!